# How get data from password protected rar file?

Tags: encryption, file-encryption

I want retrieve  documents from a password protected rar file? I know brute force and dictionary method. Is there any other method to get data?

Answer (score 5):

The current version of RAR uses 128bit AES, which is very secure. A brute force attack will be useless; and while there are some known attacks on AES, none of them are of any practical use. The specific implementation of AES they use is well respected.

That leaves:

- Guessing the password
- Dictionary attack
- Social engineering the password
- [Rubber Hose cryptography](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/security.png)

Comment: +1 for xkcd reference. I'd like to add, create a botnet consisting of the entire planets computers...

Comment: Ah, no, when people say brute force against AES won't work, they really mean it. A botnet of all the worlds computers won't have time to crack that RAR file, because *the Sun is going to be dead in only 5 billion years*.

Comment: Dictionary attacks can be surprisingly effective, as the [Crack Me If You Can](https://contest-2012.korelogic.com/stats.html) contest shows.  However, you will also note that some of the rar files (rar-medium.rar and rar-hard.rar) were not cracked at all in the time limit (48 hours).

Answer (score -3):

Using a password cracker . But it involves a dictionary attack . And Don't use brute force. 99% never works unless you are adrian lamo